# What are the differences between LD_PRELOAD and strace?

Tags: hook, system-calls, strace, ld-preload

Both methods are used to gather system calls also parameters and return values of them. When we prefer `LD_PRELOAD` and why? Maybe we can say that we can only gather syscalls via `strace` but we can gather library calls with `LD_PRELOAD` trick. However, there is another tracer for libraries whose name is `ltrace`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strace` is using the [ptrace(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) syscall (with `PTRACE_SYSCALL` probably), so will catch every system call (thru kernel hooks installed by `ptrace`). It will work on any executable, even on statically linked ones, or those using something else than your distribution's GNU Glibc (like e.g. [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/), or some assembly written utility like old versions of `busybox`).

`LD_PRELOAD` tricks use the dynamic loader e.g. `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` or `/lib/ld.so` (see [ld.so(8)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) man page) etc... so won't work with statically linked executables (or those using something else than your dynamic loader and your GNU libc).

`ltrace` is probably also `ptrace` based.

And all these are being free software, you could study their source code (and improve it).