# Why does LD_PRELOAD work with syscalls? ​

Tags: c, linux, arm, system-calls, ld-preload

The idea of `LD_PRELOAD` is to load a shared library before the original shared library, for example I can compile `mylib.so` to load it before `libc.so`, so when process wants to use `printf` it searches in the `so` that loaded one by one and finds it in `mylib.so` (because this `so` was loaded first) instead of `libc.so`, so it uses the `printf` in `mylib.so` instead of `printf` in `libc.so`.

I understand why this works on functions that are implemented in a `so` like `printf` in `libc.so`.

But when I want to hook on `write` function or another `syscall` function, why does it work? The process does not search the function in the `so`, it goes directly to the kernel.

1. Does `LD_PRELOAD` work on a binary that is compiled statically? Why?
   In this replay https://stackoverflow.com/a/13866611 mentioned that `LD PRELOAD` Doesn't work on statically binary
2. Why does `LD_PRELOAD` work on a binary compiled dynamically to make hooks on syscalls?

The architecture is ARM.

Comment: When you code calls `write` it is not directly calling a syscall. It is calling a wrapper that sets up the syscall and then traps into the kernel. So LD_PRELOAD can work by overriding the wrapper call.

Comment: @kaylum are you sure, write is syscall, that not wrapped , I can see it in assembly.So LD_PLELOAD need to work on statically binary too??

Comment: There is a syscall called write but that's not what you are directly invoking. there are syscall wrappers in libc. The preload only works with dynamically linked execs.

Comment: I've adjusted the wording of your question to make it clearer, let me know if that's ok.

Comment: Short answer: you've been lied to.  OK, that's a bit strong, but the distinction between "syscalls" and "library functions" is artificial and not really accurate.  They're all actually library functions, and what are called "syscalls" no longer really map directly to actual system calls - the actual system calls have changed.  `open()`, for example, is likely making the `openat()` system call.

Comment: This [Q/A on thumb start function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369440/can-start-be-the-thumb-function) has custom function to define syscalls, etc in your code.  You can also statically link some libraries and make others dynamic by using partial linking.  And also [static library and arm cross compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616226/how-can-i-select-a-static-library-to-be-linked-while-arm-cross-compiling/24619213#24619213) specifically has a `write()` implementation and a relevant topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The process does not search the function in the `so`, it goes directly to the kernel.

It actually does search the preloaded `so`! The syscall functions you use (`read()`, `write()`, ...) are all libc *wrappers* around the real syscalls, even the generic `syscall()` function. [Here's the code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c.html#__libc_write) for the `write()` function for example. So when you reference those, both the linker at link time, and the dynamic loader at runtime, will see a reference to an external function symbol and will need to resolve it. The only way to go directly into kernel from your program is by manually issuing a syscall (see how below).

> Does `LD_PRELOAD` work on a binary that is compiled statically? Why?

No, it doesn't. A static binary has no need to resolve any symbol dynamically, and therefore the dynamic loader is not invoked to resolve the usual library function symbols.

> Why does `LD_PRELOAD` work on a binary compiled dynamically to make hooks on syscalls?

Because those are just normal library functions, nothing more, nothing less.

---

To directly issue a syscall without passing through the C library you can use [inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). Take a look at [`man 2 syscall`](https://manned.org/syscall.2) to see which registers and instructions to use. On ARM AArch64 for example you can invoke a syscall by loading the syscall number in the register `x8`, parameters in `x0` through `x5`, and then executing the `svc #0` instruction.

Comment: So if in my code I will call to `write` directly with `syscall` like `syscall(WRITE_SYSCALL,fd, buf,nbytes);` nobady can apply `LD_PRELOAD` on this process even if it compile dinamicly ? Is my explain write? That LD_PRELOAD puts my so before any so so the loader find my function first?

Comment: No. `syscall()` is just another libc *wrapper*. As I said, the only way to do this is to either (1) link statically or (2) manually write assembly. If you don't want library functions to be hooked when linking dynamically, then *don't use library functions*.

Comment: thank you (1)  Is my explain write? That LD_PRELOAD puts my so before any so, so the loader find my function first, instead of the original function?  (2) can I see in /proc/pid that special function resolved by `mylib.so` ?

Comment: (1) yes that's right. (2) `/proc/pid/*` does not really help you. If you want to see that the function is resolved through `mylib.so` you should compile with debugging info (`-g`), then use `gdb` to start the process and do `next` until your function is called. After it's called, check its address with  `p funcname`, then check `info proc mappings` to see if the address is inside `mylib.so`.

Comment: Another way you can bypass LD_PRELOAD intercepts is to explicitly dlopen the library you want, dlsym to the function you want and call it directly.

Comment: Of course the LD_PRELOAD could intercept dlopen and dlsym and lie to you, but that would be difficult to do in a way that didn't impact other users of the methods.